# JS regex to select all <br /> that are within <p></p>'s - for function to indent text after a break

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to select all occurances of `<br />` that are within a paragraph `<p></p>` with a regular expression in JS. Currently I just select all `<br />` like this:

```
var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
```

But doing this gives me trouble at some point because of what I'm trying to do with the selection. I need a more precise regex since breaks in headlines etc. are irrelevant to me.

If you are wondering about the context of this, I want to replace the `<br />`'s with two paragraphs with suitable classes to act like a `<br />` but to indent the text after the break like this:

```
function removeEmptyNodes(selector)
{
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if  ($(this).html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
            $(this).remove();
    });
};
function assignIndents()
{
    var str = $("#content").html();
    var regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
    $("#content").html(str.replace(regex, "</p><br /><p>"));
    $('br').prev('p').addClass('br');
    $('br').next('p').addClass('indent');
    removeEmptyNodes('#content p');
    $('br').next('.scroller').children('p').first().addClass('indent');
    $('br').replaceWith('');
    removeEmptyNodes('#content p');
};
```

**Edit:**

My goal is that I have a paragraph with one or several line breaks. Like this simple case: `<p>with some text <br />and another line<p>`. I want the text after the line breaks to be indented and to be in a p of their own. So I need to split my original p. I don't want to add in divs or anything else nested in the original paragraphs. I need a bunch of sibling p tags at the end like this: `<p class="br">with some text</p><p class="indent">and another line<p>` 
By which way I replace the `<br />`'s to split the p's does not matter to me...

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This is probably better handled by finding the `<br/>` with jQuery and appending the appropriate `<p>` nodes where you want them.

Comment: @micheal I want to split an existing p, adding p's in the manner you describe would create nested p's in my original p I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just find all without a regex?

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var brs = $('br', this); //all <br>s withing this <p>
    //do something with brs
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ra8ax/

---

UPDATE:

Here is what you want with your new spec:

```
$('p').each(function(){

    var html = this.innerHTML;
    var htmlArray = html.split('<br>');
    var new_html = htmlArray[0];

    for(var i = 1; i < htmlArray.length; i++){
        new_html += "<div class='break'>"+htmlArray[i]+"</div>";
    }

    this.innerHTML = new_html;

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ra8ax/8/

---

UPDATE with no nesting:

JS:

```
$('p').each(function(){

    var html = this.innerHTML;
    var htmlArray = html.split('<br>');
    var new_html = "<p>"+htmlArray[0]+"</p>";

    for(var i = 1; i < htmlArray.length; i++){
        new_html += "<p class='break'>"+htmlArray[i]+"</p>";
    }

    $(this).replaceWith(new_html);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ra8ax/11/

Comment: because in order to add the "</p><br /><p>" which splits the original `<p>` in two at the position where the `<br />` was I need to get at the surrounding html not at the contents of the `<p>`

Comment: @C.O. -- what do you mean? did you view my fiddle example?

Comment: @Neal Thank you for the update but it's still the one p with nested divs inside that have some format. Splitting into several p's is important to my objective.

Comment: @Neal That would make nested paragraphs. I wanted all of them to be siblings. I tried to point that out but apparenty it was not clear enough...

Comment: @C.O. -- here it is without nested `<p>` -- http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ra8ax/11/

Comment: @Neal Perfect. Thank you so much. You might want to edit you update of the answer above to show the final version.

Comment: @Neal Turns out to be a royal mess... **Original XHTML:** <br />
**InnerHTML in FF 4, IE9, Safari, Chrome:** <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
**In IE8 :** <BR>
**In Opera:** <br/>

Comment: hmmmm use `$(this).html()` it should return the same for all

Comment: Nope it doesn't.. but I used this: var brLooksLike=$('<p><br /></p>').first().html(); That gets each browser's flavor of a br...

Comment: Sounds like you found a solution ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Use a Jquery selector instead of regex: `$('p br')`

---

**Update 2:**

```
$('#content')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  })
  .wrap("<p>");

var br = $('#content br');
br.prev('p').addClass('br');
br.next('p').addClass('indent');
br.remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wWsht/

Comment: Next p doesn't yet exist. That is what the original regex replace creates. Is there a better way to do that?